# How to rotate location marker in ios using carto-mobile( CARTO-SDK)

Tags: ios, swift, maps, cartodb, carto-mobile

I am using Carto-Mobile and I am trying to rotate the location marker using `CLLocation` true hedding, but I can't make it work.

I set a bitmap image to the location marker which is a `NTPoint` object, but `NTPoint` doesn't have any method to rotate according to the angle, instead of `NTMarker`, I try to use a `NTMarker` for location marker but at low zoom levels (zoom 6) never show the real position so `NTPoint` was a better fit.

So I hope anyone can tell me how I could rotate the location marker using `CLLocation` true hedding using CARTO-SDK

Regards

Comment: Generally yes, Point cannot be rotated, so you should use Markers.  Please add your code sample for the Marker style (MarkerStyleBuilder), so we see what parameter values do you have to get real marker position. Especially setAnchorPoint, which should be with 0,0 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work and keep image in precise location:

```
    NTMarkerStyleBuilder *builder = [[NTMarkerStyleBuilder alloc]init];

    // anchor 0,0 means that image is rotated from the center
    // you may have different anchor point depending on graphics
    [builder setAnchorPointX:0 anchorPointY:0];

    self.positionMarker = [[NTMarker alloc] initWithPos:position style:[builder buildStyle]];

   ...
   // rotate marker, depending on marker graphics
   // "180-course" is ok if it is "arrow down"
   // additional adjustment is for mapView rotation, image keeps
   // here correct course even if map is rotated

  double course = location.course;
  [self.positionMarker setRotation: 180 - course - self.contentView.mapView.getRotation];
```

Comment: Thanks @JaakL, like always your answer Is asserted, but why I need to set anchorPoint to 0, when this is the default value.

Comment: Default is 0,-1 meaning center/bottom. 0,0 is center/center and fits if you need to rotate image from center.